# Не могу скачать файл на русском Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь скачивать файлы названием у которых английское - проблем нет. Но когда название файла на русском, spring выводит мне само изображение и так же ошибку. Но у меня возник конкретные вопросы, могу ли я как-то это исправить и является ли такое поведение вообще "нормой" как бы странно это не звучало, просто когда я гуглил эту тему, я не особо то и смог найти какое-то решение, вот код:

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileId}")
public void downloadFile(@PathVariable(value = "fileId") long fileId, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
    
FileEntity fileEntity = fileService.findById(fileId);
    
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
    
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".doc")>-1) response.setContentType("application/msword");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".docx")>-1) response.setContentType("application/msword");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".xls")>-1) response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".csv")>-1) response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".ppt")>-1) response.setContentType("application/ppt");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".pdf")>-1) response.setContentType("application/pdf");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".zip")>-1) response.setContentType("application/zip");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".png")>-1) response.setContentType("image/png");
if (fileEntity.getName().indexOf(".jpg")>-1) response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    
log.info(response.getContentType());
    
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileEntity.getName());
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    
try {
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(UPLOAD_FOLDER + fileEntity.getUuid() + "." + fileEntity.getName());
int len;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
bos.write(buf,0,len);
}
bos.close();
response.flushBuffer();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
    
}
```

тут происходит само скачивание файла из папки, как сказал ранее, если название файла на английском - всё хорошо, у меня есть небольшая идея но я не принимаю это за решение так как не знаю является ли это правильным решение, суть решения такова, проверять название файла на наличие английских букв, если название на английском - допускать файл, именно по этому моё решение мне кажется таким себе, в ошибки как я понял проблема неким образом связанна с кодировкой, вот ошибка:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Unicode character [С] at code point [1,057] cannot be encoded as it is outside the permitted range of 0 to 255

> The HTTP response header [Content-Disposition] with value [attachment; filename=Снимокэкрана(1).png] has been removed from the response because it is invalid

Ещё есть очень важный момент, ошибка появляется в тот момент, когда я пытаюсь скачать этот файл, это очень важно, я не пытаюсь заставлять здесь кого-то писать код за меня или что-то вроде такого, не подумайте. Я просто хотел бы какую-нибудь наводку или догадку с чем бы это могло быть связанно.

Мои вопросы озвучу снова:

1. Является ли такое поведение "нормой", то есть могу ли я как-нибудь повлиять на то чтобы я мог скачивать файлы у которых название состоит из русской кириллицы?
2. В какую конкретно сторону мне копать, то есть что мне конкретно искать в качестве решения? смена кодировки или что-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, дело в том что изначально была установлена кодировка ASCll и суть в том что поддерживает она исключительно английский язык и символы, решение в виде

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

или

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

не работают для меня, я пытался что-то химичить в application.properties, но не вышло.
Основным решением было поменять кодировку у названия файла, таким образом я спокойно скачиваю свой файл с русским названием и проблем нету, вот решение:

```
String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileEntity.getName(), "UTF-8");
    
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

Я мог допустить некоторые ошибки в вышесказанном, я пока изучаю такое искусство как программирование и мало что понимаю. Всё что я описал выше это лично моё представление того, в чём конкретно была проблема. С помощью логгера Java я понял что кодировку у сервлета менялась, просто это никак не влияло на мою задачу.

Для тех кто не понял о чём идёт речь, выше, в самом вопросе была такая строка:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Она полностью работала и именно она никак не влияла на мою задачу. (Я её удалил и всё работает как надо)